# Accessing swagger generated enum values in python

Tags: python, yaml, swagger

I have defined an enum in YAML file using swagger. However, I am unable to access enum values in my python code. 
The Enum looks like

```
UnitOfMeasure:
type: string
 enum:
  - None
  - Wh
  - kWh
  - MWh
  - m3/h
```

I am reading a file and based on the content of a cell, the python code should assign UnitOfMeasure.
e.g. I am doing the following;

```
from unitofmeasure import UnitOfMeasure as um
unit1 = um.from_dict(str(sheet.cell(0,i).value))
```

If this the correct way of doing it. If yes, then when I have a value that is not contained in the UnitOfMeasure enum, instead of giving an error the program outputs the wrong values of the unit. 
Any idea of how to solve this?
p.s: I am using swagger version 2.